# Performing CRUD on a list of images displayed on html table individually per row with php and ajax or just php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Hello guys i have question to ask is it possible to Performing CRUD on a list of images displayed on html table individually per row with php and ajax or just php
for example you have a table with 4 columns for image,first name ,last name and and action button to update and delete the image of the per row like shown in the image below:

[image: This is the image link describing the table layout]

This is the php for the index page

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">

        <div class="container">

<?php include ('modal_add.php'); ?>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                    <strong><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Data Table</strong>
                </div>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">User Image</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">FirstName</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">LastName</th>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        require_once('db.php');
                        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_image ORDER BY tbl_image_id ASC");
                        $result->execute();
                        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                        $id=$row['tbl_image_id'];
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px; word-break:break-all; width:450px; line-height:100px;">
                            <?php if($row['image_location'] != ""): ?>
                            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image_location']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
                            <?php else: ?>
                            <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:300px;"> <?php echo $row ['first_name']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:200px;"> <?php echo $row ['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; width:350px;">
                             <a href="#updte_img<?php echo $id;?>"  data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-warning" >Update Image</a>
                             <a href="#delete<?php echo $id;?>"  data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-danger" >Delete </a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                        <div id="delete<?php  echo $id;?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <?php if($row['image_location'] != ""): ?>
                        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image_location']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333; margin-left:15px;">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <b style="color:blue; margin-left:25px; font-size:30px;"><?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?></b>
                        <br />
                        <p style="font-size: larger; text-align: center;">Are you Sure you want to Delete?</p>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
                        <a href="delete.php<?php echo '?tbl_image_id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                                    <!-- Modal Update Image -->
                        <div id="updte_img<?php  echo $id;?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Update</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <?php if($row['image_location'] != ""): ?>
                        <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image_location']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333; margin-left: 30px;">
                        <?php else: ?>
                        <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333; margin-left: 30px;">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <form action="edit_PDO.php<?php echo '?tbl_image_id='.$id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div style="color:blue; margin-left:150px; font-size:30px;">
                            <input type="file" name="image" style="margin-top:-115px;">
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                        </form>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                            <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is for the editing

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="container">

<?php include ('modal_add.php'); ?>

                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
                    <div class="alert alert-info">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                        <strong><i class="icon-user icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Data Table</strong>
                    </div>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">User Image</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">FirstName</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">LastName</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php
                        require_once('db.php');
                        $result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_image ORDER BY tbl_image_id ASC");
                        $result->execute();
                        for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
                        $id=$row['tbl_image_id'];
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px; word-break:break-all; width:450px; line-height:100px;">
                            <?php if($row['image_location'] != ""): ?>
                            <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image_location']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
                            <?php else: ?>
                            <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:300px;"> <?php echo $row ['first_name']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:200px;"> <?php echo $row ['last_name']; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align:center; width:350px;">
                             <a href="#updte_img<?php echo $id;?>"  data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-warning" >Update Image</a>
                             <a href="#delete<?php echo $id;?>"  data-toggle="modal"  class="btn btn-danger" >Delete </a>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                                <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="delete<?php  echo $id;?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <?php if($row['image_location'] != ""): ?>
                    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image_location']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333; margin-left:15px;">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <b style="color:blue; margin-left:25px; font-size:30px;"><?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']; ?></b>
                    <br />
                    <p style="font-size: larger; text-align: center;">Are you Sure you want to Delete?</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
                    <a href="delete.php<?php echo '?tbl_image_id='.$id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                                <!-- Modal Update Image -->
                    <div id="updte_img<?php  echo $id;?>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Update</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <?php if($row['image_location'] != ""): ?>
                    <img src="uploads/<?php echo $row['image_location']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333; margin-left: 30px;">
                    <?php else: ?>
                    <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333; margin-left: 30px;">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <form action="edit_PDO.php<?php echo '?tbl_image_id='.$id; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div style="color:blue; margin-left:150px; font-size:30px;">
                        <input type="file" name="image" style="margin-top:-115px;">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-inverse" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Yes</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is problem is that i cant update individual items

Comment: Your code is quite complex (and it seems you posted the same thing twice). Reducing complexity to the real problem would increase the chance for a good answer. And: I see a bug in your html: inside `<tbody>`, only `<tr>` is allowed (check what's before `</tbody>`)

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply Daniel Alder i ended up abandoning  upload image using ajax as it proved to be close to impossible instead i just used php but i have seen a number of people doing it but their solution didn't fit in my situation